# Copy fonts from bower_components with gulp

Tags: gulp

When I try to copy fonts from `bootstrap` & `font-awesome` which are inside of my `bower_components` folder I get such folder structure as below. But I want to have all fonts in my `dist/fonts` folder. What am I doing wrong?

**Gulp task:**

```
gulp.task('copy:bower-fonts', function() {
  gulp.src(yeoman.app + '/bower_components/**/fonts/*.*')
    .pipe(gulp.dest(yeoman.dist + '/fonts'));
});
```

**Current View:**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved this issue, used `gulp-copy`. Watch code below:

```
gulp.task('copy:bower-fonts', function() {
  gulp.src(yeoman.app + '/bower_components/**/fonts/*.*')
    .pipe(copy(yeoman.dist, { prefix: 3 }))
});
```

P.S. Dont forget to inject task: `var copy = require('gulp-copy');`